# sed - Manipulate Phone Number in xml

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I'm trying to manipulate a xml file with a bash script and sed and can't get it.
The structure in the xml looks like

```
<Name>title firstname lastname</Name><Home>+49 (30) 1234 94</Home><Mobile>+49 (171) 1234 94</Mobile>
<Name>title firstname lastname</Name><Home>+49 (30) 1234 94</Home><Mobile>+49 (171) 1234 94</Mobile>
```

I need to eliminate the `space` and `(` and `)` **ONLY** in the phone number.  After a day whis regex and sed, I could not get it. I have the string that match as needed but I can't get the groups and the right substitution.

```
sed -e 's/([0-9]\s|[0-9]\s\([0-9]|[0-9]\)\s[0-9]|[0-9]\s[0-9])/gm'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/402322

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format of the numbers remains same:

```
sed -r 's/(\+[0-9]{2}) \(([0-9]{2,3})\) ([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2})/\1\2\3\4/g' input
<Name>title firstname lastname</Name><Home>+4930123494</Home><Mobile>+49171123494</Mobile>
<Name>title firstname lastname</Name><Home>+4930123494</Home><Mobile>+49171123494</Mobile>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use ***sed*** to manipulate XML documents. 
There are good tools for that activity.
[***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is one of them.

A valid XML structure requires a root element at the top of the node tree.
Let's say we have an XML fragment (`test.xml`):

```
<root>
    <Name>title firstname lastname</Name>
    <Home>+49 (30) 1234 94</Home>
    <Mobile>+49 (171) 1234 94</Mobile>
    <Name>title firstname lastname</Name>
    <Home>+49 (30) 1234 94</Home>
    <Mobile>+49 (171) 1234 94</Mobile>
</root>
```

***The command***:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//Home|//Mobile" -x "translate(normalize-space(.),'() ','')" test.xml
```

***Details***:

`ed` - enables edit mode

`-u` - to update xml structure

`"//Home|//Mobile"` - xpath expression to select the needed elements

`-x` - to update the needed values with xpath expression

`.` (period) - points to the current selected node(s)

`normalize-space()` - the function which returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space

`translate(string, string, string)` - the function which returns the first argument string with occurrences of characters in the second argument string replaced by the character at the corresponding position in the third argument string.

---

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Name>title firstname lastname</Name>
  <Home>+4930123494</Home>
  <Mobile>+49171123494</Mobile>
  <Name>title firstname lastname</Name>
  <Home>+4930123494</Home>
  <Mobile>+49171123494</Mobile>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Name>title firstname lastname</Name><Home>0049 (30) 1234567 94</Home><Mobile>+491711234577 0</Mobile>
<Name>title firstname lastname</Name><Home>+1 39976 1234 94</Home><Mobile>+49 (171) 1234 94</Mobile>    

sed -r 's/(\+|\d*?) ([0-9]{1,})|\s\(([0-9]{2,})\) ([0-9]{2,}) ([0-9]{1,4})/\1\2\3\4\5/g' input (see above)

<Name>title firstname lastname</Name><Home>004930123456794</Home><Mobile>+4917112345770</Mobile>
<Name>title firstname lastname</Name><Home>+139976123494</Home><Mobile>+49171123494</Mobile>
```

Comment: my last favorite is `sed -r 's/\h\(|\)\h|([a-zA-Z]\h)|\h/\1/g'`